# Android socket works only in local network

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets, client-server

I cam across a pretty ridiculous problem recently...
I am creating an application that should connect to a server(written in C#) from Android(Java of course)

The code for the client(Java) is as follows:

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP); //My IP in a constant, it works with a local one...
Log.e("TCP Client", serverAddr.getHostAddress()); //Just to debug
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT); //Here I get an exception for the global IP
```

The strange thing is everything still worked yesterday... I didn't change anything concerning port forwarding, the port is still forwarded to my computer. I also set the "INTERNET" Permission in the Android Manifest.

The Server code is written in C# and is also very simple written just to test:

```
Console.WriteLine("Waitng for connection");
TcpClient client = Server.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
```

Here I won't ever get a TCPClient object because the connection times out on the client before. Nothing comes through to the server.

As said above, it's strange because everything seemed to work yesterday.

Comment: It's a java.net.ConnectException which tells me "failed to connect to /IP(port 1337)" and that the connection has timed out as said above.

Comment: Do a port scan from outside your home network and see if the port is really open. Your ISP could be filtering incoming connections above port 1024. Also, your mobile provider could be filtering outgoing to "weird" ports.

Comment: Also is the server really listening to port 1337 and a valid IP-address? As the docs state, the typical scenario is the server is not listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the case that you were connected through Wifi yesterday and now you are trying to connect through a 3G/GPRS connection. Because if you are on a Wifi Connection then it might be the case your Server and Android is on the same network causing a successful connection.

Have you made sure that the Server is accessible outside the network I mean publicly?

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the case... I was(and am still) on a wifi with my phone. And my wifi network is kind of... strange so I just rebooted the router now and changed the frequency/channel. Now it works again, also via HSDPA which is offered by my mobile ISP. Thanks a bunch, even though the solution was slightly different. The port is ok aswell :)

Comment: Great to hear...Thank you....Sometimes it is one of those tiny things that one would never look at and scratch your hair all day long...

Comment: @user2207831- I am also try make connection from c# to android EDEG/HSDPA but not succeeded. Will you please help me?

Comment: @DeepSan Is your server on a public ip address and is the port not being blocked by the firewall?

Comment: @user2207831 thanks bro. i have already solved the issue same day...Now am able to transfer data from c# to android app..